# Bootstrap 3 button not working on iPad?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following on my page:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-success" role="button" href="contact.php?c=SC"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Booking Enquiries</a></p>
```

This is on the following page of our website:
http://www.cairnsmorecottages.co.uk/stable-cottage-newton-stewart.php

It simply doesn't work on iPad and I can't, for the life of me, establish what the problem is because I've created a Bootply
http://www.bootply.com/c6aZN5Zmln

...and it works.  The code is identical so there is something else on our page that's causing the problem.  How do I track it down or can anyone help me spot what's causing the button not to work?

Much appreciated.
Thank you.
NJ

EDIT:  "It simply doesn't work" = it doesn't open the page it's linked to.
+ it does nothing (no action is performed except for button animation). Adding /contact doesn't resolve it.

Comment: How does it now work? Does it not display properly? Does it redirect you to the wrong link? Does tapping it do "nothing" (no action is performed, except for button animation)? Have you tried doing `/contact` instead of just `contact`?

Comment: It does nothing (no action is performed except for button animation). Adding /contact doesn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I would test it going to another link.  Also try opening the developer console if your iPad supports it and see if there are any errors.